# Truffle test of two transactions during the same block

Tags: web3js, truffle, testing, ganache

I'm trying to test a solidity function that only allows it to be called once per block. E.g. (my desired functionality):

1. Tx1 calls Fn during block #100, and when successful sets a boolean flag for block #100 to true, *then*:
2. Tx2 calls Fn during block #100, but gets reverted because the flag was true.

My problem is, as I can see from the logs, the transactions are mined in subsequent blocks.

Code example:

```
  contract.fn({ from: player1 }) // mined in block 100
  await contract.fn({ from: player2 }) // mined in block 101
```

Using ganache-cli with `--blockTime=10` and ganache UI w/o automine this still happens.

How do I get the transactions out one after the other, but to be mined in the same block?

Comment: Since it's for testing purposes, you can implement a helper contract which inherits (or contains) your contract, and in that helper contract, implement a function which calls Fn twice. Then, in your Truffle test, call this function and make sure that you get a `revert` exception.

Comment: One possibility is to call `miner_stop` before sending transactions and call `evm_mine` after. You might need to use `.sendTransaction` to prevent truffle from waiting for the transaction to be mined.